# Java SimpleDateformatter with 10 decimals after the seconds, cannot convert to Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, milliseconds, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to convert date string with 10 milliseconds (2018-11-02 6:05:59.1541162159 PM) to date but not able get the exact date.

Code to convert:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateFormatCheck {
    private static TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo");
    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS aa");

    public static void main(String[] a){
        try {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
            sdf.setCalendar(cal);
            cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2018-11-02 6:05:59.1541162159 PM"));
            Date date = cal.getTime();
            System.out.println(date);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Tue Nov 20 02:12:01 IST 2018
```

Comment: You're only using the toString() method from your date object.  You may want to try sdf.format(date) to get the format you want.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the **old date API** (`Date`, `Calendar`) instead of the new (`LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, ...)? If not, consider using the new.

Comment: @BrentR actually I want to convert string(2018-11-02 6:05:59.1541162159 PM) to date object

Comment: @Zabuza: No, Not any specific reason, you can suggest any new idea if you have. I just need to convert string object to Date

Comment: Aside from anything You're using `HH` which means the 24-hour time of day, but you've also got an am/pm specifier. I suspect you mean `h` instead fo `HH`.

Comment: @Zabuza: It's really *not* parsed to the right value. An input of 6:05:59 shouldn't end up as 02:12:01... it's handling the milliseconds value as 1541162159 milliseconds, rather than it being 0.1541162159 of a second.

Comment: @Zabuza: My output date is Tue Nov 20 02:12:01 IST 2018 actually it should be Tue Nov 02 18:05:59 IST 2018

Comment: Adjust your format, it is wrong and does not correspond to the input you are using.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've also tried yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS aa format. but failed

Comment: @Zabuza: what should be the format then.

Comment: You may want to edit your title and body - it's not that you have "10 milliseconds" - they're not milliseconds at all. They're 10 digits representing the fraction of a second. The problem is that SimpleDateFormatter really is treating it as 1541162159 milliseconds, which is over 17 days. That's why the date is so far off.

Comment: That input format is a bit screwy,  zero-padding the minute but not the hour. Where possible, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats instead for exchanging date-time values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are multiple problems at the moment. I'd *strongly* recommend using `java.time` for as much work as possible, although even that doesn't make this easy.

As you say, your value has 10 digits for "fraction of a second" - which means it goes down to 10th-of-a-nanosecond precision. That's highly unusual to start with, in my experience - and I don't *think* Java can handle that, even with `java.time`.

I suspect you'll need to massage the data first, down to 9 digits of precision. At that point, it's fairly straightforward to parse the value to a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
// Note this only has 9 digits of precision, not the original 10
String text = "2018-11-02 6:05:59.154116215 PM";
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
    "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS a", Locale.US)
    .withZone(zone);
ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
System.out.println(parsed);
```

Note how I've provided `SSSSSSSSS` as the fraction-of-a-second part, to handle all 9 digits. Also note the use of `h` instead of `HH` - `HH` would mean "24-hour hour of day, with 0 padding" - neither part of which is true for your original value, which uses "6" for 6pm. It's very rare that you would want to combine `H` or `HH` with `a`.

That code gives you a `ZonedDateTime`, which you could convert into a `Date` like this:

```
Date date = Date.from(parsed.toInstant());
```

I'd recommend you *don't* do that unless you really, really need to for interop reasons though; the `Date` API is nasty in various ways.

Comment: Good one, but still waiting if anyone can make it with 10 digits in milliseconds as I have a fixed length of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the date first with your SimpleDateFormat object:

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Edit: Do this once the parsing issue is resolved to print it out correctly.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is the parsing.

Comment: Ah yeah true. Even with the parsing fixed, they aren't printing the date object correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String dateText = "2018-11-02 6:05:59.1541162159 PM";
        String[] parsedText = dateText.split("\\.");
        String[] parsedText2 = parsedText[1].split(" ");
        String newText = new StringBuilder(parsedText[0]).append(" ").append(parsedText2[1]).toString();
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a", Locale.US)
                                                                                                 .withZone(zone);
        ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(newText, formatter).plusNanos(Long.parseLong(parsedText2[0]) / 10);
        System.out.println(parsed);
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to read it with SimpleDateFormatter:

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(date.getTime()));
```

If you want read it with default date format:

```
private static String[] daysOfWeek = new String[]{"SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"};

private static TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Colombo");
private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS aa");

public static void main(String[] a){
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);

        sdf.setCalendar(cal);

        cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

        cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2018-11-02 6:05:59.1541162159 PM"));

        System.out.println(
                daysOfWeek[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)] +
                        new SimpleDateFormat(" dd hh:mm:ss yyyy").format(cal.getTime()));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: That prints "WED 19 08:42:01 2018" for me. Definitely not the same thing as November 2nd. (SimpleDateFormat just doesn't handle this value.)